# C++ create new pointer from existing value

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

How do i create a pointer from a value argument?

## attempt 1

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Both {
public:
  T1 *lx;
  T2 *rx;
  Both(T1 _lx, T2 _rx) {
    lx = new T1;
    rx = new T2;
    *lx = _lx;
    *rx = _rx;
  }
  ~Both() {
    delete lx;
    delete rx;
  }
};

class cls {
public:
  int x;
  cls(int v) : x(v) {}
};

Both<cls, cls> b(cls(1), cls(2));
```

This will cause an error

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'cls'
> lx = new T1;

And I would not want to enforce all arguments for `Both` must have a default empty constructor.

## attempt 0

Prior to this I attempted to implement `Both` as

```
Both(T1 _lx, T2 _rx) : lx(&_lx) rx(&_rx) {}
```

And I got a warning

> warning: initializing pointer member 'rx' with the stack address of parameter '_rx' [-Wdangling-field]
> Both(T1 _lx, T2 _rx) : lx(&_lx), rx(&_rx) {}

## attempt 2

```
Both(T1 _lx, T2 _rx) {
  lx = (T1*) malloc (sizeof(T1));
  rx = (T2*) malloc (sizeof(T2));
  *lx = _lx;
  *rx = _rx;
}
```

gives a abort signal

> FAILED: {Unknown expression after the reported line} due to a fatal error condition:
> SIGABRT - Abort (abnormal termination) signal

My intended use case for `Both` is for the user to call `delete` manually after they are done

Thus to reiterate, how do I convert a non pointer value passed from an argument to a pointer?

Comment: why do you pass by value when the class is all about pointers but no values? You are storing pointers to the constructor parameters, ie they are invalid pointers once the constructor returns

Comment: Why manually `delete`? Your code doesn't compilant with [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), so it may cause some trouble when the objet of `Both` is copied.

Answer (score 1):

1. Allocate a new object
2. Copy the value of arguments there
3. Assign the pointers to the members

```
Both(T1 _lx, T2 _rx) : lx(new T1(_lx)), rx(new T2(_rx)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your types are copyable, you were *almost* there with the first attempt.

```
lx = new T1{_lx};
```

This one should actually work. Or - if your types are not copyable -

```
lx = new T1{std::move(_lx)};
```

You should however be aware that your class does not comply with the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Your best option in this scenario is using a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. Generally, `new` should not be used at all unless you are designing your own smart pointer or container.

Answer (score 0):

`cls`'s only constructor is one that takes an int, and `new` is obliged to call a constructor on a newly-allocated memory chunk. By defining `cls::cls(int)`, you hindered generation of `cls::cls()` - the default constructor, so it is impossible to call `new` without providing constructor parameter.  The second attempt is able to be compiled (although still isn't working) because there was no constructor call, and malloc() does not call contructors at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
lx = new T1;
rx = new T2;
```

what constructor is used here?
It's not what you provided `cls(int v) : x(v) {}` because this one does demand `int v`

A solution would be to have a defaulted constructor, a void constructor, or a constructor with all arguments set as default.

- cls(int v = 0) : x(v) {} // a constructor with all arguments set as default
- cls() = default; // a defaulted constructor
- cls():x(0){} //  a void constructor

Choose any, but only a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the insights, I'm still not familiar with standards in C++ development so all of your feedback is appreciated.

I've chosen a solution that does not require non pointer value to pointer conversion and tried to stick to a *rule of three* class.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Both
{
public:
  T1 lx;
  T2 rx;
  Both(T1 _lx, T2 _rx) : lx(_lx), rx(_rx) {}
};
```

and I can simply do the following for pointers

```
cls *x = new cls(1);
cls *y = new cls(2);
Both<cls*, cls*> b(x, y);
REQUIRE((b.lx)->x == 1);
REQUIRE((b.rx)->x == 2);
```